# Stop next execution of Rxjs observer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, rxjs, rxjs6

I am trying with the basic use case of a Rxjs observer. This is what I am doing:

```
const { Observable } = require('rxjs');

Observable.create(o => { 
  setTimeout(() => o.next('hi'), 1000); 
  setTimeout(() => { throw new Error('A mistake') }, 1500); 
  setTimeout(() => o.next('this should not print'), 2000) }
).subscribe({
  next: x => console.log(x),
  error: y => console.log('error', y),
  complete: () => console.log('done')
});
```

The out put of this is the following:

```
> hi
Error: A mistake
    at Timeout.setTimeout [as _onTimeout] (repl:1:89)
    at ontimeout (timers.js:498:11)
    at tryOnTimeout (timers.js:323:5)
    at Timer.listOnTimeout (timers.js:290:5)
> this should not print
```

What I need to do is stop the execution of the next, and even If I `unsubscribe` my subscription it is not stopping the next execution.

I tried like this too:

let subscription;

```
let source = Observable.create(o => { 
  try {
    setTimeout(() => o.next('hi'), 1000); 
    setTimeout(() => { throw new Error('A mistake') }, 1500); 
    setTimeout(() => o.next('this should not print'), 2000) 
  } catch (e) {
    subscription.unsubscribe();
    return 'error';
  }
});
subscription = source.subscribe({
  next: x => console.log(x),
  error: y => console.log('error', y),
  complete: () => console.log('done')
});
```

but no chance... it did not stop.

What I have as code is not just set timeout I have async and await code like this:

```
let subscription;

let source = Observable.create(async o => { 
  try {
    o.next(await anEvent()); 
    o.next(await anEventThatThrowsAnException()); 
    o.next(await anEventThatIWantToAvoidDueToTheException()); 
  } catch (e) {
    subscription.unsubscribe();
    return 'error';
  }
});
subscription = source.subscribe({
  next: x => console.log(x),
  error: y => console.log('error', y),
  complete: () => console.log('done')
});
```

How can I achieve this code to stop the "this should not print" ?

Comment: try using `o.error('A mistake')` instead of generic error

Comment: Well that would actually execute the error clause... but it does not stop the next asynchronous code to execute

Comment: what do you mean "does not stop the next asynchronous code to execute"? I can see "this should not print" is not printed

Comment: Can you provide an answer with your code? I run it several times with different ways, it is always printing the console log

Comment: here you are https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-pragqe

Comment: Jesus, you are right, it is working just fine, I just missunderstood the way to work with errors of observables... thx for the example and the patience

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the way to make it work with observer.error as stated by ABOS. In fact this is his example and it works.

So Just for documentation purposes I answered this question with his answer from the comment.

[ABOS answer](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-pragqe)

I just thought that if someone is having problem trying to handle errors throwing the error instead of catching and executing observer.error in the way that is needed.

Answer (score 1):

After you set the timer with `setTimeout`, you will not prevent it's execution with `unsubscribe`.

You will need to manually clear your timeouts.

Note that you can save your timeouts in variables `var myTimeout = setTimeout(f,ms);` then you can cancel then `clearTimeout(myTimeout);`

Read More:

- [setTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout)
- [clearTimeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout)

Comment: Yeahp I know about those examples, the actual implementation is just as an example of asynchronous code... so what I have is async and await calls...